# Sitecore AB Testing issue - 8.2 Update 5

Tags: content-testing

I have setup a AB Test at page level in Sitecore 8.2 Update 5 and cancelled it manually.

When I try to setup the same AB Test again, it is throwing an error message in Experience Optimization.

Do you have any ideas to overcome this issue? Is there anyway to restart the same test that was cancelled previously?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Chandra Sekaran

Answer (score 1):

The cancelled ab testing was associated to the page within Content Editor Standard Values for that item.

Once I removed the association, I was able to create a new AB test again.